# Retornar valor no Header de um chamada HTTP (POST) na API

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, http-headers

Estou usando o Postman para fazer a chamada na API.
Que me retorna esse resultado no body:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

que vem dessa classe abstrata:

```
public abstract class ResponseBase
{
    public long SessionId { get; set; }
}
```

que após pegar o valor da propriedade cai nesse metodo da classe `BasicAuthHttpModule`:

```
 private static void OnApplicationEndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
        //response.AddHeader("SessionId", )
        if (response.StatusCode == 401)
        {
            response.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate",
                string.Format("Basic realm=\"{0}\"", Realm));
        }
    }
```

Como eu passo o valor da propriedade `SessionId` para o `Header` do response?

Nessa classe `OnApplicationEndRequest` não tenho acesso ao `SessionId`, não sei aonde ele fica armazenado, para ser passado no retorno e aparecer o valor no PostMan.

Comment: O que é esta classe `ResponseBase`?

Comment: @jbueno varias actions na API retornan o SessionId, as classes delas herdam essa classe para ter acesso.